# Postgres counting elements and columnize by date

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Ok Postgres geniuses, I need some help. I am trying to chart a large amount of data and want to prepare the data as best I can in the db before sending over to the frontend. I am using Postgres 9.6

I have a set of results like this:

```
Source  | Date
--------|------------
Email   | 2017-06-01
Email   | 2017-06-01
Email   | 2017-06-03
Email   | 2017-06-03
Email   | 2017-06-03
Email   | 2017-06-04
Email   | 2017-06-06
Email   | 2017-06-06
Email   | 2017-06-07
Banner  | 2017-06-01
Banner  | 2017-06-02
Banner  | 2017-06-03
....
```

And I need to get it all counted by day then columnized and if there is a zero result for a date I need zerofilled.

Desired result:

```
Source  | 2017-06-01  | 2017-06-02  | 2017-06-03  | ...  | 2017-06-07
--------|-------------|-------------|-------------|------|------------
Email   | 2           | 0           | 3           | ...  | 1
Banner  | 1           | 1           | ...
```

I hope this makes sense, thank you.

Comment: how many columns of dates do you need? is it fixed?

Comment: No the columns aren't fixed. I could also perhaps send back a single column that is json of all the values but it would have to have a zero value if it does not have any records for that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    crosstab(
    $$
        SELECT "Source", "Date"::text, count("Date") 
        FROM t 
        GROUP BY "Source", "Date"
        ORDER BY "Source"
    $$,
    $$
        SELECT cast(d as date)
        FROM generate_series(date '2017-06-01', date '2017-06-10', interval '1 day') as s(d)
    $$
    ) AS  
    (
        "Source" text, 
        "2017-06-01" bigint,
        "2017-06-02" bigint,
        "2017-06-03" bigint,
        "2017-06-04" bigint,
        "2017-06-05" bigint,
        "2017-06-06" bigint,
        "2017-06-07" bigint,
        "2017-06-08" bigint,
        "2017-06-09" bigint,
        "2017-06-10" bigint
    ) ;
```

Which uses the [`crosstab(text source_sql, text category_sql)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html#AEN185129), specific to PostgreSQL and that needs the `tablefunc` extension, or you can go the "classical SQL pivot":

```
SELECT
    "Source"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN "Date" = '2017-06-01' THEN 1 END) AS "2017-06-01"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN "Date" = '2017-06-02' THEN 1 END) AS "2017-06-02"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN "Date" = '2017-06-03' THEN 1 END) AS "2017-06-03"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN "Date" = '2017-06-04' THEN 1 END) AS "2017-06-04"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN "Date" = '2017-06-05' THEN 1 END) AS "2017-06-05"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN "Date" = '2017-06-06' THEN 1 END) AS "2017-06-06"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN "Date" = '2017-06-07' THEN 1 END) AS "2017-06-07"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN "Date" = '2017-06-08' THEN 1 END) AS "2017-06-08"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN "Date" = '2017-06-09' THEN 1 END) AS "2017-06-09"
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN "Date" = '2017-06-10' THEN 1 END) AS "2017-06-10"
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    "Source"
ORDER BY
    "Source" ;
```

```
Source | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-02 | 2017-06-03 | 2017-06-04 | 2017-06-05 | 2017-06-06 | 2017-06-07 | 2017-06-08 | 2017-06-09 | 2017-06-10
:----- | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
Banner |          1 |          1 |          1 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0
Email  |          2 |          0 |          3 |          1 |          0 |          2 |          1 |          0 |          0 |          0
```

Both will return the same values, with the difference being the second will give you '0' and the first will give you 'null' when there are no values to count.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=80bd50004c30bd55195026ea78f37798)*

Comment: Ok follow up question, is there a way to build the select statement so the date range is dynamic. Say I to create a function where I pass the start and end dates and then have it dynamically build the columns out from that?

Comment: You can do that with a function together with dynamic SQL. Check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg-dynamic.html

Comment: Wow that is getting a little (or a lot) over my head. Is there an example possibly you can link to that might be similar. I tried googling postgres and dynamic sql and got a ton of different tangents. If not thanks, this has already been extremely helpful.

Comment: This *is* difficult, specially since you actually want to have a function that *generates* a query, then *executes* that query. You just don't change parameters, you're changing the *columns* that will be reported. Sorry, I am not sure where to find an adequate example... this *ain't* easy.

Comment: I understand, it is a difficult problem. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

This query can be used for non-periodic date range.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CROSSTAB(
            $$
                SELECT id, 
                    fdate::TEXT,
                    fveri
                FROM   tmp_table 
                
                WHERE fdate = '05.11.2020' 
                OR    fdate = '08.11.2020' 
                OR    fdate = '11.11.2020' 
                OR    fdate = '14.11.2020' 
                OR    fdate = '17.11.2020'

                ORDER BY 1, 2
            $$,
            
            $$
                SELECT CAST(m AS date) FROM generate_series( date '05.11.2020' , date '18.11.2020' , interval '3 day' ) m
            $$
        ) AS tmp ( tmpid integer, 
                    "201105" varchar(50), 
                    "201108" varchar(50), 
                    "201111" varchar(50),
                    "201114" varchar(50), 
                    "201117" varchar(50)
                )
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=95f56c27456ffc389dfb071387d6bef5

Samples were taken from Page